# UIslider thumb image doesn't start from the beginning

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am trying to implement a control to show progress of a video and I am  using a UISlider with a custom thumb image but the thumb image doesn't start from the beginning and it doesn't go till the end as well.

```
playerProgress = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake((btnImage.size.width + 2 * VideoViewControllerUX.ControlPadding), 0, (screenRect.size.width - (btnImage.size.width + 3 * VideoViewControllerUX.ControlPadding)), btnImage.size.height))
playerProgress.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "slider"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
playerProgress.maximumValue = 100
playerProgress.minimumValue = 0
playerProgress.addTarget(self, action: "playerProgressChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

[image: Slider Image 1]

I am not sure whats going on.

- Thumb Image:

  [image: Thumb Image]

Comment: What is the thumb image supposed to look like? That control looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: @CraigOtis I have added the thumb image(Its in white color just right click next to text and download ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal. The slider leaves some extra space at both ends, so that the thumb is at minimum or maximum value when the *edge* of the thumb is at the end of the slider frame.

Look at these sliders. They have the same horizontal positions and width:

[image]

The first slider's thumb is as far to the left as it will go. It doesn't go further left, *outside* the frame of the track; it stops when its *edge* hits the the frame of the track. That is zero.

If you don't like *where* the thumb *image* is being drawn in relation to the overall track, you'll need to subclass UISlider and implement `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`.

Comment: Yeah I did what you suggested before posting the question. When I override  the thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value: the slider stops working(it doesn't slide).

Comment: override func thumbRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
        let thumbImage = UIImage(named: "slider")!
        let thumbImageSize = thumbImage.size        
        return CGRect(x: -10, y: 0, width: thumbImageSize.width, height: thumbImageSize.height)
    } I have added the above code then the slider stops working(doesn't move)

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. You need to implement `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` _correctly_. Obviously _your_ implementation is ridiculous: if you give the same return rect no matter what the incoming `value` is, the slider won't move.

Comment: @matt this actually happens even if you set the thumb image to same it already was by `slider.setThumbImage(slider.thumbImageForState(.Normal), forState: .Normal)` with the only requirement being that it must be some custom image (e.g. different thumb tint). If you wonder why someone would do that, is because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903317/uislider-behaviour-in-ios7-versus-ios6

Comment: I fixed this issue with the same approach at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502400/uislider-with-thumb-center-over-the-start-and-end-of-track/53068606#53068606

Answer (score -2):

I have created the similar slider by subclassing UISlider.

```
//Get thumb rect for larger track rect than actual to move slider to edges
-(CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value {
    UIImage *image = self.currentThumbImage;

    rect.origin.x -= SLIDER_OFFSET;
    rect.size.width += (SLIDER_OFFSET*2);
    CGRect thumbRect = [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];
    return CGRectMake(thumbRect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+2, image.size.width, image.size.height);
}

//Make track rect smaller than bounds
-(CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds  {
    bounds.origin.x += SLIDER_OFFSET;
    bounds.size.width -= (SLIDER_OFFSET*2);
    CGRect trackRect = [super trackRectForBounds:bounds];

    return CGRectMake(trackRect.origin.x, trackRect.origin.y, trackRect.size.width, trackRect.size.height);
}
```